# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined erorr showing after saving a change?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am getting this annoying error after making a slightest change to my code and ctrl and save...
Then this error shows the app, freezes and I have to reload the page again... any idea?
I never got this error before...
It appeared out of no where, below is the error and my package file.
My app doesn't have any backend to it, so I wonder what is causing the error.

Error in the console of the web browser :

```
VM188:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object.4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at Object.8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
    at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
    at <anonymous>:2:315627
    at <anonymous>:2:324225
    at <anonymous>:2:324229
    at HTMLIFrameElement.e.onload (index.js:1:1)
```

`package.json` :

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.4",
    "npm": "6.14.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.60",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "@types/html2canvas": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.2",
    "@types/jspdf": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.6",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.10",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "html2canvas": "^1.3.3",
    "jspdf": "^2.4.0",
    "notistack": "^1.0.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to access `process.env` in some way. Can you post the code that is causing the error?

Comment: @yainspan happens on the whole app i could show my package.json

Comment: What was the change to your code that triggered the error? And does removing the change make the error go away?

Comment: @yainspan I remove package.lock nodemodules because  I had some issues , then installed them again... maybe this is the reason ?

Comment: Something tells me that somewhere in your app, you're trying to access `process` from the browser environment. Where are you using that variable?

Comment: @Vektor I found this import in my code could it be it ? 
import { url } from 'inspector'; I dont recall adding it , not at pc now..

Comment: I'm uncertain, as I'm unfamiliar with that library. The question does require more context and information before we give a meaningful response. I would suggest looking through similar q/a to get an idea of what the source of the issue could be, and maybe post the code where you're using the `process` variable like what @yainspan mentioned.

Comment: @Vektor it wasn't the library it causes the issue, the issue happens when i  deleted node modules and more likely package-lock why would deleting package.lock causes this ??  and how to solve it if I want a clean start

Comment: I also have same issue, when I save any changes and then page is not working i must have to reload a page. This happens once I update my node modules and `react-scripts`  to v50.0.0 but now i again downgrade to v4.0.3 and getting this error. @Richardson Let me know if you find any solution

Comment: @Jitendra Solanki so it happens to you only when you down grade ? I solve it by getting my backup package.lock but still I want to know the root cause. From what I understand it is a web pack issue  apparently you should never ever delete the package-lock , but still I think there might be a clean solution..

Comment: @Richardson yes it's happened after downgrade. i have deleted all node modules and package.lock file and then reinstall everything. i don't have old lock file :(
If i put old package.lock file then it will work? i mean delete all node modules, put old lock file and then reinstall. is it correct?

Comment: @Jitendra Solanki if you can find the old file and put it back it would probably work try it you wont lose any thing ...

Answer (score -1):

After long discussion with [@Richardson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17274449/richardson) in question comments, here I am posting my working solution. I can't find root cause of error but possible issue is...

When I update `react-scripts` library to v5.0.0 then application stop working so again I downgrade `react-scripts` to v4.0.3 and then facing `process is not defined` error. After downgrade `react-scripts` when I have installed `node_modules` it has updated some dependency in `package-lock.json` file and it causes an issue.

Only solution I found is as suggested by [@Richardson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17274449/richardson) I just add old `package-lock` file and reinstall `node_modules` (you can also try by delete existing `node_modules` put old `package-lock` file and install modules again) and it works!!!

Comment: I did remove node modules as well didn't work.

Comment: @Richardson after delete `node_modules` again you have to put old `package-lock` file and install `node_modules` it will work.